# woocommerce for wordpress remove add to cart button

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Are there any woocommerce experts out there that know how to remove the add to cart button from the shop page? I only want that button displaying on the individual item pages.

Also, I would like to change the order of the title and price. I would like price to be displayed directly below the image and the title below the price. Where in the template do I change this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find the following file in the woocommerce plug in directory

wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/content-product.php

and remove the line that says like below

It will remove the Add To Cart Button for each product in the Shop page, retaining the Button in the Single Product Page.