# How to remove add to cart button from shop page in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to remove add to cart button from the shop page, product category page and home page in woocommerce. But i want to show it on the product page. That meance i want my costumers to open product page to add the product to cart.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [woocommerce for wordpress remove add to cart button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12047745/woocommerce-for-wordpress-remove-add-to-cart-button)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Woocommerce - How to remove the Add to Cart Button on product listing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12135190/woocommerce-how-to-remove-the-add-to-cart-button-on-product-listing)

Comment: Kindly, but this is clearly a duplicate as there is multiple answers on StackOverFlow for this.

Answer (score 1):

To remove add to cart button from product page. you need to override the product page template .

So locate to woocommerce directory find the below path .

wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/content-product.php

and remove the text which says - It will remove the Add To Cart Button for each product in the Shop page, retaining the Button in the Single Product Page.

Comment: I do not find any such line in content-product.php. i am adding the content of that file to my question section .

Comment: Hmmmm...   I cant add the whole code here.    I just found a single line about the add to cart and that is a comment. * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart - 10
  */

Comment: I dont think that removing that comment will do any thing

Comment: @user6952436 you dont need to remove comments , you need to remove that code which contains this comment

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'remove_add_to_cart_buttons', 1 );

```
function remove_add_to_cart_buttons() {
  if( is_product_category() || is_shop()) { 
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart' );
  }
}
```